# default consumer group id in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I am working with Kafka 2.11 and fairly new to it. I am trying to understand kafka consumer groups, I have 3 spark applications consuming from same topic and each of them are receiving all the messages from that topic. As i have not mentioned any consumer group id in applications I'm assuming that Kafka is assigning some distinct consumer group id to each of them. 
I need to reset kafka offset for one of the application using below command.As I don't know the consumer group name of my application I'm kind of stuck here. Do I  need to explicitly assign group id in application and then use it in the command below?

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --to-datetime 2017-11-1907:52:43:00:000 --group <group_name> --topic <topic_name> --execute
```

If this is true, how can I get consumer group id of each application? I can't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consumer `group.id` is mandatory. If you do not set consumer `group.id`, you will get exception. So obviously you're setting it somewhere in your code or the framework or library you're using is setting it internally. You should always set `group.id` by yourself.

You can get the consumer group ids by using the following command:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server <kafka-broker-ip>:9092
```

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Spark code you can find `KafkaSourceProvider` class, that is responsible for Kafka source reader, you can see that random group.id is generated:

```scala
private[kafka010] class KafkaSourceProvider extends DataSourceRegister

  override def createSource(
    sqlContext: SQLContext,
    metadataPath: String,
    schema: Option[StructType],
    providerName: String,
    parameters: Map[String, String]): Source = {
      validateStreamOptions(parameters)
      // Each running query should use its own group id. Otherwise, the query may be only assigned
      // partial data since Kafka will assign partitions to multiple consumers having the same group
      // id. Hence, we should generate a unique id for each query.
      val uniqueGroupId = s"spark-kafka-source-${UUID.randomUUID}-${metadataPath.hashCode}"
    ...
  }
```

You can search group.id with `spark-kafka-source` prefix, but you can't find group.id for particular group.

To find all consumer group ids you can use following command:
`./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server KAFKKA_ADDRESS --list`

To check consumer groups offsets you can use following command:
`./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server KAFKKA_ADDRESS --group=GROUP_ID --describe`

Answer (score 1):

> As i have not mentioned any consumer group id in applications I'm assuming that Kafka is assigning some distinct consumer group id to each of them

The Kafka brokers don't assign consumer group names to consumers connected to them.
When a consumer connects, subscribing to a topic, it "joins" a group.
If you are using Spark application without specifying any consumer group, it means that in some way the library/framework you are using for connecting to Kafka from a Spark application is assigning consumer group names itself.